# How to sort strings in a pre decided order in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need a sorting function to sort an array with an order of b->c->a, without defining new array.

input.sort(func) => output

Input: ['b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a']

Output: ['b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a']

Comment: code monkey, lol

Comment: @KenWhite It's a Javascript question

Comment: It doesn't matter what language it's in. It's a *plz givez me teh codez* question. Javascript is categorized as *code*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
d = {b:1,c:2,a:3}
var result = ['b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a'].sort(function(v1,v2){
  return d[v1]>d[v2];
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass an array of strings which will resemble the sort order. Now iterate this argument using `forEach` and use `filter` to filter out the elements from the main array .`filter` will return an array. Push the elements from the filtered array to main array.

```js
var input = ['b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a']

function customSort(sortOrderArray) {
  var outPutArray = [];
  // iterate the input order array
  sortOrderArray.forEach(function(item) {
    // now from the original array filter out the elements which are matchin
    var m = input.filter(function(items) {
      return item === items
    })
    // m will be an array
    // using spread operator & push this array to outPutArray
    outPutArray.push(...m)
  })
  return outPutArray;
}
console.log(customSort(['b', 'c', 'a']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
var input = ['b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a'];
var order = ['b', 'c', 'a'];

input.sort((e1, e2) => order.indexOf(e1) - order.indexOf(e2))
// output: ['b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a']
```